# Array destructuring with complex nested object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following line with destructuring syntax;

```js
const [
  {data: dataResponse},
  {data: stateDistrictWiseResponse},
  {data: statesDailyResponse},
  {data: stateTestResponse},
  {data: sourcesResponse},
  {data: zonesResponse},
] = someArr;
```

`someArr` is an array of objects (actually result of `Promise.all([url1, url2,...]`, where each url returns a json object)

How is the above destructuring syntax evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

The values extracted via destructuring syntax closely parallels the syntax of an object literal. For example, if `someArr` is defined as (or contains):

```
const someArr = [
        {data: 'dataResponse'},
        {data: 'stateDistrictWiseResponse'},
];
```

then the syntax

```
const [
        {data: dataResponse},
        {data: stateDistrictWiseResponse},
] = someArr;
```

will put the `'dataResponse'` string into the `dataResponse` variable, and the `'stateDistrictWiseResponse'` string into the `stateDistrictWiseResponse` variable.

The colon after the property indicates that the property is being extracted into a variable whose name is on the right of the colon. (If there is no colon when destructuring, the value is put into a new variable name which is the same as the property name, eg `const { data } = someObj` creates a variable named `data` which holds the value at `someObj.data`).

Your original code is quite hard to read though. I'd highly recommend mapping to create a new array of only the `data` properties first, *then* destructuring:

```
const dataArr = someArr.map(({ data }) => data);
const [
  dataResponse,
  stateDistrictWiseResponse,
  statesDailyResponse,
  stateTestResponse,
  sourcesResponse,
  zonesResponse,
] = dataArr;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...actually the "someArr" does not really have the structure as {data: 'dataResponse'} 

Instead it looks something like 
{
 "cases_time_series": [
  {
   "a1": "1"
   
  }
 ],
 "statewise": [
  {
   "a2": "2"
  }
 ],
 "tested": [
  {
   "a3": "3"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Then the code you posted in the question will not extract any properties, so they'll all be `undefined`

Comment: Actually I just had a quick followup....So you indicted the difference based on whether there is colon after the property or not.

What I tried is without the colon;
var [
        {A},
        {B},
] = someArr;

Now, I was expecting variables "A" & "B" to get/contain the values...But I see they are undefined after executing the above line of code...

So, not sure if this is really destructuring syntax or something else is going on...